# Using components outside of controllers in CakePHP

Tags: php, email, cakephp, components

Is it possible to use the built-in CakePHP components (eg: `EmailComponent`) as standalone classes?

I know this probably shows a design flaw, and that I'm not doing it the Cake way or something, but I have a class which is not tied to any Model/Controller and I want that to be able to send emails. Importing the EmailComponent doesn't work, since it tries to read information from `$this->Controller` which is obviously null in this situation.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

```
App::import('Core', 'Controller');
App::import('Component', 'Email');
$this->Controller =& new Controller();
$this->Email =& new EmailComponent(null);
$this->Email->initialize($this->Controller);
```

See comment 11 of [EmailComponent in a (cake) Shell](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/view/emailcomponent-in-a-cake-shell#4630), should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [App::import](http://book.cakephp.org/view/529/Using-App-import).

```
App::import('Component', 'Email');
$email = new EmailComponent();
```

Note that you might need to pass `null` as a parameter in the constructor since I think it might normally be expecting a reference to the controller.  This might cause issues with regards to the `EmailComponent` locating layouts and views though, you'll have to play around.

Comment: I think that's exactly the problem the OP is having. The EmailComponent uses controller functions at a few points, so passing `null` won't help much.

Comment: @deceze: yep, hit the nail on the head.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the cake way to do this is to make the component a vendor, if that's not too much of a pain.  Then it would be accessible anywhere in the codebase.  You could use this code in the beforeFilter and use it just like a component in your controller.

```
App::import('Vendor', 'EmailVendor');
$this->EmailVendor = new EmailVendor($this);
```